# How to avoid start of Gradle daemon inside Dockerfile

Tags: docker, gradle, dockerfile, gradle-daemon

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM gradle:6.3-jdk8 as builder
WORKDIR /
COPY . /
RUN gradle shadow --no-daemon
EXPOSE 9999
CMD ["java", "-jar", "search-all.jar"]
```

I want to avoid Gradle daemon starting every time I build the image. Is there any possibility or a workaround to achieve this? I mentioned the `--no-daemon` but it is still started.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question has already an extensive answer on the Gralde forums: [Using –no-daemon, but still see a process called “Gradle Worker Daemon 1”](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/using-no-daemon-but-still-see-a-process-called-gradle-worker-daemon-1/28698/2).

In short: The Gradle daemon process is the one executing the build and started always no matter on what has been specified on the command line. If `--no-daemon` is specified, the process is terminated after build completion.

Original answer from the Gradle forums:

> > **My question is why is the daemon being created when we specify --no-daemon?**
>
> The process run by Gradle to execute a build is the same whether or not you enable or disable the daemon. The behavior of the process after a build completes is the difference.
>
> With the daemon enabled, the process will continue running in the background and can reused for a subsequent build. With the daemon disabled, the process is terminated at the end of the build. Even with the daemon disabled, you will still see a process labeled as a daemon. It doesn’t mean it will continue running in the background like a daemon.